# How can i select messages from buffer of node , using python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, buffer, message-queue

I want to stock messages in **buffer**, then select **n messages** from the buffer to send them.  and I will use Python.
I know that "**recv()**" function makes the msg stock in buffer. but I don't know how to select from it n messages.

Comment: "**recv()**" serves to receive, not _to send_.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.